# Questions about total disconnectedness

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I have come across the proof that the Cartesian product of totally disconnected sets is also disconnected in the following post.

[Product of totally disconnected space is totally disconnected?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/550650/product-of-totally-disconnected-space-is-totally-disconnected)

1. However does the above theorem extends to arbitrary product spaces also? (I.e. A component where $x_\alpha$ and $y_\alpha$ does not differ can
2. Also, what would happen if we have two distinct points such that the component for x is always a subset of y? (I.e. having $x_\alpha= \{\frac{1}{3}\}$  and $y_\alpha= \{\frac{1}{3},\frac{2}{3}\}$, will the proof still works?
3. Finally is it possible to have X to be totally disconnected but having some $X_i$ to not be totally disconnected?

Thank you!

Comment: (1) The proof given there is for arbitrary products. (2) The components are all singletons. (3) No.

Comment: Thanks! but could you explain why (3) doesn't holds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For (3): If some $X_i$ is not totally disconneted, there is a connected component $Y_i \subseteq X_i$ which is not a singleton. Now choose $x_j \in X_j$ for every $j \in I \setminus \{i\}$, and define
$$ \hat Y_i := Y_i \times \prod_{j \in I\setminus\{i\}} \{x_j\} $$
Then $\hat Y_i$ is homeomorphic to $Y_i$ and hence connected and not a singleton. But $\hat Y_i$ is a subspace of $X$. Contradiction.