# There is no continuous bijective function from $ \{ 0,1 \}^\mathbb{N}$ to $[0,1]$

Tags: general-topology

I am trying to prove that there is no continuous bijective function from $ \{ 0,1\} ^\mathbb{N}$ to $[0,1]$ where $\{0,1\}$ has the discrete topology, $\{ 0,1 \}^\mathbb{N}$ has the product topology and $[0,1]$ has the usual topology (order topology).

I don't know how to start, I tried by contradiction, but I don't really see the contradiction. Could someone give me a hint? I feel like it's something simple but I really don't see it.

Comment: Hint: prove first that these spaces are not homeomorphic.

Comment: Hint: If you have a continuous bijection from a compact space to a Hausdorff space, what can you say about its inverse?  (recall closed subsets of compact spaces are compact, and compact subsets of hausdorff spaces are closed)

Comment: Hmmm, maybe the combination of these two hints sort of gave the game away:)

Comment: @MW Thank you, that helps a lot. I think I can use connectedness to show that they are not homeomorphic. Is $\{ 0,1 \}^\mathbb{N}\setminus \{a\}$ connected?

Comment: @AlejandroPeralta As User's answer explains, its totally disconnected, even without removing a point.  Also another (more or less equivalent) route would be to say $f^{-1}$ can't be continuous since then composing with projection onto first coordinate would give a continuous surjection from $[0,1]$ to $\{0,1\}$.  Then you don't really think about the product topology as much, other than the fact projections onto coordinates are continuous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MW gives in their comment half of the solution: if you have a continuous bijection $f$ from a compact space to a Hausdorff space, then $f$ is a homeomorphism. We have that $\{0,1\}^{\Bbb N}$ is compact by Tychonoff's theorem.

If there's a continuous surjection $f: [0,1] \to \{0,1\}^{\Bbb N}$, then $\{0,1\}^{\Bbb N} = f([0,1])$ is connected. However, since $\{0,1\}$ is totally disconnected (discrete topology), [then so is](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/550650/product-of-totally-disconnected-space-is-totally-disconnected) $\{0,1\}^{\mathbb N}$. This is a contradiction.

Comment: Thank you very much, I didn't know that the product of totally disconnected is totally unconnected.

Comment: @AlejandroPeralta my pleasure!